# Why material-ui components don't display in my App?

Tags: reactjs

So I'm following a react tutorial and in that project material-ui is being used, it's e-commerce, so I have Products.jsx and Product.jsx files.

Product.jsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardMedia, CardContent, CardActions, Typography, IconButton} from '@material-ui/core';
import { AddShoppingCart } from '@material-ui/icons';
import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

const Product = ( {product} ) => {

    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
                <Card className="rootie">
            <CardMedia className="media" image='' title={product.name}  />
            <CardContent>
                <div className="cardContent">
                    <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                            {product.name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                            {product.price}
                    </Typography>   
                </div>
                <Typography variant="h2" color="textSecondary">{product.description}</Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions disableSpacing className="cardActions">
                 <IconButton aria-label="Add to cart">
                     <AddShoppingCart/>
                 </IconButton>
            </CardActions>
        </Card>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}

export default Product;
```

Products.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import Product from '../Product/Product';
import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

const products = [
    { id: 1, name: 'JBL', description: 'JBL', price: '$100'},
    { id: 2, name: 'AirPods', description: 'AirPods', price: '$100'},
];

const Products = () => {
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <Grid container justifyContent="center" spacing={4}>
                    {products.map((product) =>{
                        <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                                <Product product={product}/>
                        </Grid>
                    })}
            </Grid>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}

export default Products;
```

And my App.js looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Products from './components/Products/Products';
import './App.scss';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Products/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

So as you see, everything looks okay, but for some reason React doesn't render the components, so the page looks empty. I've searched on the internet and found about 'MuiThemeProvider', but adding it didn't really help either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a theme and pass it as prop to `ThemeProvider` which in turn  wraps the entire App during ReactDOM.render stage itself. Something like this:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import App from './App';
import theme from './theme';

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
    <CssBaseline />
    <App />
  </ThemeProvider>,
  document.querySelector('#root'),
);
```

Only then will your Material UI components work as you expect.

Comment: so should i delete MuiThemeProvider from other components?

Comment: Yes, you can delete them. The `ThemeProvider` class takes care of injecting the MUI theme into all the components.

Comment: i was wondering, you said i should import 'theme' file, but what's this file? should i write it myself or it's part of react?

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/create-react-app/src/theme.js). This project is a template created by MUI folks for a react app. You can use it as reference.